# Pre populated anchor tab width height issue

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending an anchor tab which is shown to signer as pre filed with his name. Everything works fine, the only issue is, when I send widht height elements for this tab, it doesn't take any effect.

Any idea why ? Here is anchor tab xml snippet-

```
<fullNameTabs>
   <fullName>
      <anchorString>/fn1/</anchorString>
      <width>150</width>
      <height>50</height> 
   </fullName>
</fullNameTabs>
```

other things to note here, I have used a range of values starting from 0 to 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, none of them took effect.

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

FullNameTab does not respect width and height. I'm sorry this is not clearly documented.
This tab adjusts the size based on the full name and that's that.
If you want this capability, you'd need to switch to a TextTab and set the value to be the name of the signer. You can also make it read-only if you don't want them to be able to change it.